# Why does my app keep opening from the background everytime a splash screen is changed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, splash-screen

I have created an app with 3 splash screens. They appear and disappear after 10 seconds and the next one takes its place until the 3rd one ends then the main activity is opened and the app works as it should.

The problem is if the user sends the app to the background during any of these splash screens, after 10 seconds the app will bring itself back to the front even if the user is using another app and display the next splash screen or the main activity.

I looked over the code and can't seem to find anything that would explain this. it was working fine before Android Studio updated to 3.5, I have no idea why that would cause this problem.

```
public class  loadScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
private int SLEEP_TIMER = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_screen);
    LogoLauncher logoLauncher = new LogoLauncher();
    logoLauncher.start();
}

private class  LogoLauncher extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(3000 * SLEEP_TIMER);
        }catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(loadScreen.this, createdby.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        loadScreen.this.finish();


    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
}
```

I expect that if the app were to be sent to the background during the splash screen sequence when the user returns to it, it will resume from when where they left it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that startActivity will be called even if your app is in the background. That will open your app when called. So you need to create some logic in that section to check if it's allowed to call the startActivity method.

Edit: 
Code for checking the pending start for activity. Give this a try!

```
private static final String PENDING_LAUNCH_KEY = "PENDING_LAUNCH";
private boolean pendingLaunch;
private boolean activityPaused;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        pendingLaunch = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(PENDING_LAUNCH_KEY);
    }

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_screen);

    if (!pendingLaunch) {
        LogoLauncher logoLauncher = new LogoLauncher();
        logoLauncher.start();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    activityPaused = false; 

    if (pendingLaunch) {
        pendingLaunch = false;
        startAndFinish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    activityPaused = true;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    outState.putBoolean(PENDING_LAUNCH_KEY, pendingLaunch);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
}

private class  LogoLauncher extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(3000 * SLEEP_TIMER);
        }catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (activityPaused) pendingLaunch = true;
        else startAndFinish();
    }
}

private void startAndFinish() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(loadScreen.this, createdby.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: How would you recommend I do that?

Comment: Thanks pal. you are a live saver

Answer (score 1):

> the app will bring itself back to the front even if the user is using
>   another app

Your thread is still running even you app goes to background!, 
Solution is,
You must have to `terminate` that thread in `onPause` method

> it will resume from when where they left it.

**SplashActivity**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Handler handler = null;
private long SPLASH_TIMEOUT = 5000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    handler = new Handler();
}

private Runnable splashRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent mySuperIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, SplashActivity1.class);
        startActivity(mySuperIntent);
        finish();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    handler.removeCallbacks(splashRunnable);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    handler.postDelayed(splashRunnable, SPLASH_TIMEOUT);

}
}
```

**SplashActivity1** same code of SplashActivity only `intent` will change.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

private Handler handler = null;
private long SPLASH_TIMEOUT = 5000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash1);
    handler = new Handler();
}

private Runnable splashRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent mySuperIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity1.this, 
MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mySuperIntent);
        finish();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    handler.removeCallbacks(splashRunnable);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    handler.postDelayed(splashRunnable, SPLASH_TIMEOUT);

}
}
```

Comment: How do I implement your suggestions?